# Python MYSQLdb documentation missing details?

Tags: python, database, mysql-python

I am trying to make sense of  [MySQLdb](http://mysql-python.sourceforge.net/MySQLdb-1.2.2/) documentation. I was just wondering if there are things missing from there. For example, I am trying to see what "rowcount" (a constant) actually does, but am not seeing it anywhere in the documentation.

So is the documentation incomplete or am I just looking at the wrong place?

Thanks.

Comment: You can also have a look at the [DB-API](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/), which afaik MySQLdb implements.

Comment: Have you tried the pydoc documentation? Run an interactive shell, import MySQLdb, run a query, and run `help(Cursor.rowcount)`. I can't guarantee that the documentation will be there, but it's worth a shot.

Comment: @Chris: +1 for the pydoc comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The primary source of documentation for Python database modules is [the DB-API 2.0 specification](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/):

> ```
> .rowcount 
>
>        This read-only attribute specifies the number of rows that
>         the last .execute*() produced (for DQL statements like
>         'select') or affected (for DML statements like 'update' or
>         'insert').
>
>        The attribute is -1 in case no .execute*() has been
>         performed on the cursor or the rowcount of the last
>         operation is cannot be determined by the interface. [7]
>
>        Note: Future versions of the DB API specification could
>         redefine the latter case to have the object return None
>         instead of -1.
> ```

Answer (score 2):

I found this [tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_database_access.htm) on MySQLDB useful. Rowcount is mentioned, but not used in one of the examples.

Answer (score 1):

Well after poring through the source code, here's the relevant line (MySQLdb/cursors.py:120)

```
self.rowcount = db.affected_rows()
```

So `rowcount` is just a member variable for the `Cursor` class (not a method), which happens to hold the result of `affected_rows`. I guess it probably saves you a call to that particular function.

Answer (score 0):

I used the following google search: `rowcount site:mysql-python.sourceforge.net`

It is often better to use google `site:` operator to search a site than to use the site's native search.  But  your right, it doesn't have it's own documentation.

Comment: I admire the google-fu, however you neglected to actually click on the link. There is no function called `rowcount` on that page. There is `field_count` and `affected_rows`, both of which recommend that you DO call `Cursor.rowcount`.

Comment: Interestingly, `Cursor.rowcount` seems to be undocumented, which may be why the OP is asking this question...

Comment: @chris:I didn't mean it as an Fu, not everyone knows about the site: operator.  You're right, I mis-read the link, but then corrected my post almost immediately.

Comment: I hate the internet some days, I can't type 10 words without accidentally invoking some kind of profanity.